# Setting Document Font to sylfaen

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, font-encodings

Could you please recommend how can i set PDFLatex Document font to Sylfaen for Georgian language.
Below is my current setup which doesn't work.

```
\documentclass [a4paper, georgian, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A,T8K,T8M]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,russian,georgian]{babel}

\fontfamily{sylfaen}\selectfont
\renewcommand\rmdefault        {sylfaen}
\renewcommand\familydefault    {\rmdefault}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's an truetype font it would be easiest to use lulatex or xelatex I get this with lualatex

[image]

```
\documentclass [a4paper, georgian, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,russian,main=georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={mode=harf}]{sylfaen.ttf}


\begin{document}

Გამარჯობა მსოფლიო
\end{document}
```

The first character is apparently not available in the font, the log warns:

```
Missing character: There is no Გ (U+1C92) in font [sylfaen.ttf]:mode=node;scri
pt=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;mode=harf;!
```

oh script=latn is probably wrong, it may be better if I gave a better script tag.

Comment: Thank you! Actually it works. The Missing character error is due to capitalization. The only question which i have now is about the letter tracking. I used \usepackage[letterspace=25]{microtype} Which seems not affecting anymore on this font. Any Idea how can it be fixed. Thanks in advance

Comment: fontspec can specify letterspacing directly to the font without microtype try adding `,LetterSpace=10`  to the argument above

Comment: You can get the missing-character warning in the console, instead of silently logged, with `\tracinglostchars=2`.

Comment: In 2020, you also probably want `Renderer=Harfbuzz` instead of the raw feature.  Or the default might work.

Comment: You would want to set the main font with something like `\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Sylfaen}`, with additional options following `Scale=` as needed.  This will set the correct OpenType script and language tags for the current language.